# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my NativeScript with Angular project, I'm just trying to simply use an object to gather information on a user. Whenever I do this, I get an error that says `ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.user.username')`. I tried to recreate this in the NativeScript Playground but it wouldn't recognize my model.

So, here's my model:

```
export interface User {
    id: number,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    permissions: string,
    year: number,
    basketball: boolean,
    dodgeball: boolean,
    football: boolean,
    soccer: boolean,
    softball: boolean,
    volleyball: boolean,
    teamID: number
}
```

Here's my .ts component:

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

    public user: User;

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    nextSignUp(): void {
        alert(this.user.username);
        this.router.navigate(['/signUpInfo']);
    }
}
```

and then here's my .html file where I use my ngModel:

```html
<ActionBar title="Sign Up" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout class="pageBackground">
 <ScrollView>
  <StackLayout class="main-container">
   <TextField style="margin-top: 3%;" class="form-control" hint=" Email Address" keyboardType="email" returnKeyType="done" autocorrect="false"
    autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="user.username"></TextField>
   <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-sm" style="width: 90%; height: 7%; padding: 0px; margin-top: 77%; background-color: black; color: white; vertical-align: bottom;"
    text="Next" (tap)=nextSignUp()></Button>
  </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this error or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interface is only providing the type to user var. Initializing user var with empty obj or with empty username field might work in this case.

Comment: @Ajay that was my first thought as well, but then it just changed the error to `evaluating this.user.username = ""`

Comment: ngOnInit() {

this.user = {
 'username': ' '
}; } This should work.

Comment: @Ajay that's what I had tried, but I finally found it. for some reason, the .js file that's created whenever you create a .ts file for nativescript in VS wasn't updating, so I just had to delete it and refresh. Thanks!

Comment: @rcarcia02 I get the same error. How do you delete the .js file and refresh it? I don't know where to find it in VS code.